# difference between facts, knowledge and wisdom

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain the difference between a `fact`, `knowledge` and `wisdom`?

Comment: Knowledge is knowing that a tomato is a fruit, wisdom is not putting it in a fruit salad.

Comment: To attain knowledge, add things every day. To attain wisdom, subtract things every day. -Laozi

Comment: @iterums great quote, I was very impressed by your inventiveness until I found it' [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Kington) :).

Comment: @terdon I just read that somewhere and found it fitting here. Thanks for the source.

Comment: Have you looked this up in a dictionary? If so, what do you find confusing about the definitions? If not, then why not?

Answer (score 2):

1. A fact is a single piece of information.
2. Knowledge is the accumulation of information, techniques, and skills. You may have knowledge of simple facts, such as world capitals, or skills, such as fire making.
3. Wisdom is generally meant to include the higher order of intelligence that includes judgement, morals, and decision-making.

Answer (score 1):

A fact is indisputable. It can be verified repeatedly, and is not subjective.

Knowledge is what you know - know-ledge.

Wisdom is having good judgement, such as being able to judge when to consult a dictionary.